Automatically selected field does not show in React <select>
Here is my React code:
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { accountContext } from "../context/AccountContext/accountContext";


export default function AddAccount() {
  const { createAccountAction , error} = useContext(accountContext);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    accounttype: "",
    initialBalance: "",
    notes: "",
  });

  //handle form change
  const handleChange = e => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // formData.accounttype = (formData.accounttype === "")?"Saving":formData.accounttype;    
    createAccountAction(formData);
    
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex min-h-full flex-col justify-center py-12 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
          <h2 className="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900">
            Add Account
          </h2>
        </div>

        <div className="mt-8 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-md">
          <div className="bg-white py-8 px-4 shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:px-10">
            <form className="space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div>
                <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                  Name
                </label>
                <div className="mt-1">
                  <input
                    value={formData.name}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    className="block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-400 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                  Initial Deposit ($)
                </label>
                <div className="mt-1">
                  <input
                    value={formData.initialBalance}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    name="initialBalance"
                    type="number"
                    className="block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-400 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div>
                <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                  Account Type
                </label>
                <select
                  name="accounttype"
                  value={formData.accounttype}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  className="mt-1 block w-full border-2 rounded-md border-gray-300 py-2 pl-3 pr-10 text-base focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                >
                  <option value="Saving">Savings</option>
                  <option value="Current">Current</option>
                  <option value="Business">Business</option>
                  
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                  Add Note
                </label>
                <div className="mt-1">
                  <textarea
                    rows={4}
                    name="notes"
                    type="text"
                    value={formData.notes}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className="block w-full border-2 rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="flex w-full  justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-indigo-600 py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
                >
                  Add New Transaction
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


In above code when I fill all fields except accounttype field it sends null. I want to send automatically selected accounttype value to the server.
In this example it does not select Account Type option and fill all the other fields but it does not automatically select Account Type option
How to fix this code?

to add a default value for anything you should set it in the initial state.

If you set a default value in the useState hook, it should have an automatic value, so instead of leaving an empty string for accountType try


  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    accountType: "Checking",
    initialBalance: "",
    notes: "",



or whatever other kind of account you want to be the default.
Hope this helps!
